# Error ingresando datos con carbon a base de datos

Tags: php, laravel

### Mensaje de error:

> `throw new InvalidFormatException(implode(PHP_EOL, $lastErrors['errors']));`

Este es el código que utilizo:

```
public function store($request)
{
    $dates = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $request->date_submit . ' '. $request->time_submit);
    return self::create([
        'dates' => $dates->toDateTimeString(),
        'doctor_id' => $request->doctor,
        'status' => 'pendiente',
        'user_id' => $request->user()->id

    ]);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio. No se agrego tu código, por favor utiliza el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/363499/edit) y proporciona tu código. Puedes mirar [ask]

Comment: Creo que el error es de Carbon, y no al insertar en BD. Que valores tienen esos inputs date_submit y time_submit del request?

Comment: si creo que es eso pero nada intento ingresar a la base de datos pero nada siempre me sale ese error, los valores de date_submit es de fecha, y el valor de time_submit es la hora.     speciality:1, doctor:doctor,
date: 9 June, 2020,
date_submit:2020/06/09,
time:4:30 PM,
time_submit:16:30

Comment: soy un primiparo en la programacion esto es un proyecto que me toca entregar para poder graduarme. ya he leido documentacion en carbon en laravel y nada :(

Comment: Entonces le estás pasando otro formato Y-m-d, pero tu date_sumit es Y/m/d. Prueba así `$dates = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i', $request->date_submit . ' ' . $request->time_submit);`

Comment: muchas gracias si era ese error